# How to get a string value from a method C#

Tags: c#, methods

so I'am trying to create a method where there's going to be a string value in it and then I want to get that value from the main method

```
public string test(string stringVar)
    {
        stringVar = "Hello world";
        string anotherVar = stringVar;
        return anotherVar;
    }
```

For example in this code how can I get the variable 'anotherVar' to be recognized in the main method?

Thanks.

Comment: Your main method is probably static. Try to set your method static and then call it . public static string test(string stringVar)

Comment: You need to assign the *result* of this method to something in the main method. The scope of `anotherVar` is restricted to this method

Comment: The variable `anotherVar` is a local variable. That, by definition, means it can't be used by name outside the method. So taken literally, the only correct answer to your question is "you can't". Please be more specific as to what you really want to do if you want an answer you can _use_. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: var result=test("yourstring"); inside your main method.

Comment: You *might* want to pick up a book on structured programming. Object oriented programming might help a bit as well. What's your programming background? JavaScript? PHP?

Answer (score 3):

If I have correctly understood what you want,somewhere in your main you just have to call the method. For example:

```
string desiredResult=test("someString");
```

desiredResult will than store the value being returned.

Comment: Thanks to your help, somehow I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In console app your main is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

so you have to create a static function

```
public static string test(string stringVar)
```